# wordpress комментарии

Tags: wordpress

На странице **записей** есть комментарии, как мне добавить эти же комментарии на **отдельной странице**.Можно ли как-то сделать отдельную страницу с комментариям, и подскажите где искать файлы внутри шаблона?

**Решение**

Добавить в нужный шаблон выбор записей через `WP_Comments_Query`. Например:

```
$comments = new WP_Comment_Query( [ 'post_id' => 0 ] );
wp_list_comments( [], $comments->comments );
```

Comment: А на кой эти же комменты где-то ещё?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

За вывод комментариев в twentyseventeen отвечает шаблон comments.php. Смотрите в него, разбирайте код. Комментарии привязаны к записям, поэтому на отдельной странице надо будет сделать цикл по записям.

Comment: Нет, мне не нужна отдельная страница с отдельными комментариями, которые отвечают только за эту страницу

Comment: Тогда ваш вопрос вообще непонятен. Напишите подробно, чего вы хотите. Название страницы, ее примерное содержание, что за комменты вы на ней хотите увидеть, с примерами.

Comment: И я вам не предлагал "отдельную страницу с отдельными комментариями, которые отвечают только за эту страницу". В моем ответе есть словосочетание "цикл по записям".